# Assembly numpy array by piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for fast way of assembling the numpy array by an interval function. Here is my present code (simplified) which consumes a lot of time for creating subarrays:

```
import numpy as np

def func():
    a = np.random.random(10000) # avarage size of my arrays
    b = np.random.random(10000)
    r = np.zeros_like(a)

    ind = np.where(a > 0.1)[0]  # some data close to limits is always cut
    ind = ind[a[ind] < 0.9]

    ind2 = ind[a[ind] <= 0.3]  # first interval
    r[ind2] = a[ind2] * b[ind2]  # exemplary calculation

    ind = ind[ind != ind2][0]

    ind2 = ind[a[ind] <= 0.8]  # second interval
    r[ind2] = a[ind2] * b[ind2] * 5

    ind = ind[ind != ind2][0]

    ind2 = ind[a[ind] > 0.8]  # even up to 20 intervals (can be done in loop, 
                                        # here shown separated for clarity)
    r[ind2] = a[ind2] * b[ind2] * 10

    return r
```

I will be grateful for every hint.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the function is suppose to achieve?  The example code you've given (1) doesn't return anything, and (2), `r[ind2]` always results in an empty array.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected code. Function is suppose to assign values of r with piecewise-defined function.